# Javascript: Return promise in nested function

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I have this code:

```
createOrUpdate({
    test: 'test'
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

which will expect a createOrUpdate to return a promise. Here is the createOrUpdate function:

```
function createOrUpdate(requestParams) {

    var options = {};

    return getService('global', function(error, serviceResult) {
        if (error) {
            log.error(error);
            return callback(error, null);
        }

        //...

        return requestPromise(options);
    });

}
```

I have this getService method that takes some paramaters and a call back. I need to get that `return requestPromise(options)` to return when createOrUpdate is called, but currently it is not working. I get an error saying I cannot call then on what createOrUpdate returns.

Ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you assign getService() to a variable, say: `var func = getService(...)` and then have: `return func()`?

Comment: `getService()` doesn't return a promise so when you do `return getService()` you don't get a promise that you can use.  You probably want to promisify `getService()`.

Comment: Sadly it was marked as duplicate while I was typing.. So I can't add it as an answer.

https://gist.github.com/WORMSS/a6bbfa94ad9a3aa99b03c0d9f461ff3b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, you need to make `getService` into [a promise returning API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).

Otherwise, node-callback taking functions don't `return` anything and ignore their own return values.

```
function createOrUpdate(requestParams) {

    var options = {};

    return fromCallback(getService)('global').then(options => 
        requestPromise(options);
    );

}
```

Comment: What if I cannot make getService a promise returning API?

Comment: @PepperedLemons then you wrap it in one.

Comment: Yup. Looks like bluebird makes it easy! http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.fromcallback.html

Comment: @PepperedLemons look at `promisifyAll` it's even nicer.

Comment: Where does `fromCallback()` come from?  I know Bluebird has such a function, but it's `Promise.fromCallback()` and you don't make any mention of Bluebird in your answer.

Comment: I didn't mention bluebird because it's not required - I referenced an answer that shows how to convert a callback API and then just used "fromCallback" here as a descriptive name to what that answer does (for the node callback example). OP _can_ use bluebird and its `fromCallback` or they can use the code or logic from the answer linked above. If you think I should clarify further please let me know.